# Set default text for google plus share widget?

Tags: google-plus

Im using the share on google+ widget. Is it possible to set the default text for the post?

Ive found a few posts on stack about using meta tags but they havn't worked for me:

`<meta property="og:description" content="Custom text" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prefill text using [interactive posts](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive). They require a little more work to setup but it should provide what you need.